# Prove the Inequality on sequence

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

$a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ ,

$b_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$.

Show that $b_n-\frac{3}{2n} < a_n < b_n$.

Answer (score 1):

From the binomial theorem we have

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1n \right)^n &=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)}{n^k}\frac{1}{k!}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\right)\frac{1}{k!}\\\\
&\le \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\\\\
\end{align}$$

since all of the terms $\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)<1$.

Comment: How to get the other side of the inequality??

Comment: One way to show the other side makes use of the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$ is monotonically increasing and bounded above by $e$, while $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n+\frac{3}{2n}$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded below by $e$.  Can you use this approach?

Comment: Sorryy!! Unable to get a clear idea..!

Comment: can u please gibve an eaborated andwer??